# How to determine target of Annotation using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations

Assume I have a runtime annotation `@foo` with `@Target({ElementType.PARAMETER})`.

Also assume that I use it to annotate a method:

```
void someFunction(@foo Bar bar) {
  // ...
}
```

I have an instance `Annotation annotation` that corresponds to the annotation in `someFunction` above.

Is there anyway to use my instance `annotation` (and reflection) to determine the type of the parameter `bar` is of type `Bar`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, given an instance of your annotation, you cannot determine specifically what it's annotating.

The [`Annotation`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html) interface exposes [`annotationType()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Annotation.html#annotationType--) which will give you access to the annotation type (yours). You can therefore use the corresponding `Class` to [retrieve](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getAnnotation-java.lang.Class-) the value of the `Target` annotation on your type. That's the best you can do.

---

Note that `Annotation` is **just** an interface. I can create instances of it like any other.

```
new Annotation() {
    @Override
    public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
        return Target.class; // whatever
    }
};
```

Comment: doesn't Java EE have a way of figuring out type?  For example, you can inject various classes with `@Inject` or `@Resoruce`.  There has to be some way the annotation can figure out the corresponding class

Comment: @aguibert The opposite happens in that case. The framework scans the fields and checks if they are annotated with `@Resource` or `@Inject`. You start with the field, not with the annotation.